# what is difference between protected static method and protected method?

Tags: java

What is difference between `protected static` method and `protected` method? For example `demo` and `demo2` in `Data2` respectively

Data.java:

```
package pack1;

import pack2.*;

public class Data extends Data2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("From main class");
        Data d=new Data();
        d.first(); 
    }

    void first(){
        Data2 d2=new Data2();

        d2.demo();
        d2.demo2();
    }
}
```

Data2.java:

```
package pack2;

public class Data2 {
    protected static void demo(){
        System.out.println("In method demo");
    }

    protected void demo2(){
        System.out.println("In method demo2");
    }
}
```

Comment: You posted your code, but you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 5):

A static method is a method which doesn't belong to a particular instance of a class. It belongs  to the class itself.

You could write `Demo2.demo()` to call the static method directly on the class without creating an instance. But you couldn't call `Demo2.demo2()` because demo2 isn't static and thus can only be called on an instance you created with the `new` keyword.

Because a static method is not (necessarily) bound to a specific instance of a class, it can only access static variables (the value of static variables is shared between all instances of a class while the value of a non-static variable is different for each instance you create with the `new` keyword).

You might wonder *"what's the reason for a static **protected** method, considering that it's impossible to call it from anywhere except from an instance of that class?"*. Usually there isn't much reason to declare a private or protected method as static. Static methods are usually public. But when the behavior of a method does not affect or is affected by the state of the current instance, declaring it static can be a way to document this fact.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that code artifacts can be a form of documentation and not necessarily functionality.

Comment: So how would you call a static protected method from an imported api or jar

Comment: You said: "it's impossible to call it from anywhere except from an instance of that class" but that's not exactly right since it can be called by other classes in the same package. In which case package visibility may be more appropriate.